# Problem adding a book to Careers

Tags: support, jobs

I'm trying to add a book I've written to my Careers profile to no avail.

The book has ISBN (978-84-615-9841-0). The book is written in Catalan and the ISBN was registered in Spain. A search in the Spanish database gives the correct result.

Here is the link to the search engine for Spanish books: http://www.mcu.es/webISBN/tituloSimpleFilter.do?cache=init&prev_layout=busquedaisbn&layout=busquedaisbn&language=es

Can I add my own book? How?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like they just use Amazon as their source for searching for books, not any sort of actual database of all books with an ISBN. It appears if it's not on Amazon.com, you can't add it, at least at the moment.

Notice the explicit Amazon logo next to the link to add a book:

[image: Amazon logo]

As well, all the results returned link to the product page for the book on Amazon.

Comment: Right, I thought that. I was expecting some alternative aside of publishing my book with Amazon. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Regardless of the current state of affairs, I'd like to petition the StackExchange staff to reconsider only relying on Amazon as a canonical source for, "This is an actual book."

Related: [Careers: Cannot Add Book](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/265921/256181)

If nothing else, being able to search or reference by ISBN number will be a serious win for anyone who is published but does not sell through Amazon.

Furthermore, prompting users, "Don't see your book here? Click here to add it" and giving them a form to fill in the details manually would make sure no one falls through the cracks.

As it stands, the system is, "If it doesn't make Amazon money, *it doesn't count*."

Comment: +1. Another thing would be a provision to add URL (if exists) of the book page in addition to form/section to add book details.