# Careers: Cannot Add Book

Tags: support, feature-request, jobs

I recently put together an e-book, [*Using Libsodium in PHP Projects*](https://paragonie.com/book/pecl-libsodium). In addition to covering installing the sodium cryptography library and libsodium PHP extension from PECL, it covers the entire public-facing API and contains a section dedicated to recipes that developers can reference when designing their own features with libsodium.

I thought this would make a great addition to [my StackOverflow Careers profile](https://careers.stackoverflow.com/scott.arciszewski), but it won't let me add it. (I'm not going to drop it in the blog posts section, since it's not a blog post.)

When I attempt to add my book, the only interface that I'm offered is this search box which is not aware of this e-book. I cannot find a "Can't find your book here? Click here to add it manually" form anywhere.

[image: Screenshot]

If possible, I'd like a permanent solution to this rather than a workaround. I'm sure this will affect other people down the line. (I also intend to publish more free online technology books!)

Comment: As explained [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/155317/152859), you can only add books which are available on Amazon. (SE are using Amazon API to locate the book) - guess this ensures you are adding actual book.

Comment: So if I have no intention on letting Amazon make money off my work, it doesn't count as an actual book. Great.

Comment: Feel free to upvote the original feature request, start a bouny, edit if you can add details etc, but nothing we can do beyond that.

Comment: Done. Let's hope the community has any say in what SE does. (Who am I kidding? Of course we don't.)

Comment: Well, since Careers are the main money making revenue of SE, there is a higher chance they will listen to what the users have to say. :)

Comment: That's a good point. I hope you're right.

Comment: I added a bounty, it expired. Nothing was resolved.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. If it's any comfort, non-careers requests suffer a lot more. Highly popular requests sit for years, without getting a bit of official attention. One of those is [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121954/add-a-confirmation-before-moving-comments-to-a-chat), I've also tried a bounty in the past to no avail. We just have to live with the fact that vast majority of the requests will never be done, or even get any kind of response from the team. (luckily for me, I'm active enough here to have lots of spare rep, so tried again now with fresh bounty)

Comment: Oh my, I just noticed you bountified the wrong question. You should have placed a bounty on the original feature request that this question is dupe of. Since I feel guilty, I started a bounty now. Chances are still low that it will cause a difference, but who knows.