# Make it clear that we can only add books which are available on Amazon

Tags: feature-request, jobs, books

When adding a book to our Careers profile, this is the UI:

> [image]

However, when searching (which is the only way to add) the results are only from Amazon. Can it please be made clear that we can expect only Amazon results, e.g. by adding icon, or text?

Comment: +1 for this... How do we trace the UI change... is there anyway to track for it?

Comment: Not sure what you ask, @Hacker?

Comment: I mean to say... is there any way to track (like revisions) for this UI change? Look this feature was there before and got removed at some point... new UI change, possibly

Comment: Oh, no way to track it. If there's no update from a developer, we can't really keep track on those changes. (unless having some auto screen scraping of some sort)

Comment: Thanks. But I bet internally SE team can track the changes took place over the time.

Comment: @HackerKarma well, as can be seen [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10370/152859) SE developers are using Git source control, so it means all code changes can be easily tracked.

Comment: That's right... I forgot about that. So, its traceable. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I second this feature request. It would be great to have an Amazon icon or text note if SO Careers is using Amazon as their ***only*** source for searching for books.

In fact, there used to be an Amazon logo next to the link to add a book but somewhere down the line (new UI) it got removed. Here is excerpt from  moderator animuson's answer on the post ["Problem adding a book to Careers"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/155317/254554) :

> Notice the explicit Amazon logo next to the link to add a book:
>
> [image: Amazon logo]
>
> As well, all the results returned link to the product page for the
>   book on Amazon.